# Cant get function parameter javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I'm trying to get the parameter of a js function to be alerted. I com from swift and I find some things confusing.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('users');

rootRef.on('child_added', snap => {
var username = snap.child('username').val();
var email = snap.child('email').val();
var uid = snap.child('uid').val();
var pp = snap.child('profile_picture').val();

var nopp = '';
var noppmsg ='';

if (pp == null) {
    var nopp = 'display: none;'
    var noppmsg = 'No profile image';
}
$('#users_table_body').append('<tr><td>' + noppmsg +'<img src ="'+ pp + '" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 50%;' + nopp +'"></td><td style="text-transform: capitalize;">'+ username +'</td><td style="text-transform: capitalize;">' + email +'</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-light add-friend" onclick="add_friend(' + uid + ')">Add friend</button></td></tr>');
});

function add_friend(uid) {
console.log(uid)
}
```

I'm trying to get the uid to the function via a button that is appended. as shown in the code above the button onclick executes the function add_friend and gives the parameter uid from the closure and then in the function that parameter is logged on the console, but it isn't working.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9UOC.png)

[image]

Comment: are there any errors in the console? or does it do nothing?

Comment: i just added an image!

Comment: Apparently, you reference an unknown variable. You must add another couple of quotes for the printed value to be considered a string.

Comment: its globally scoped, ill try it :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to add another `""` pair:

```
 'add_friend("' + uid + '")'
```

So that when the uid gets inserted it ends up as:

```
add_friend("wgdhebhx");
```

Comment: Correct. In the original code `onclick` was trying to send a variable, named like your uid, but not the uid. As such var does not exist - error

Comment: having this error now SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Comment: If `uid` is a number you don't need quotes around it.

Comment: @barmar that assumption was made based on the error the OP showed, which some uncautious refactorerer removed by accident